# How to merge two files into a new one and compare with other one

Tags: sorting, awk, cat

I need help. I have some files

```
file 1, file 2 and file 4
```

example:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u file1 file2 > file 3
```

But I need:

```
file 3 - file 4 = file 5
```

How do I do it? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: That `sort` command is ignoring standard input so the `cat file1 file2 |` part of that command line is doing nothing. I also don't at all understand what you are trying to do or what problem you are having. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: The command you want is PROBABLY `comm` but it's very hard to tell from your question. Post some samples of the files and your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I need: file 3 - file 4 = file 5

To create a file5 which has all the lines from file3 **except** for the lines that also appear in file4:

```
grep -vFf file4 file3 >file5
```